# md-grid-tile with ng-if occupy twinkle

Tags: angular-material

i want use md-gid-tile with `ng-if` or `ng-show`
but `ng-show` use occupy the space. [#6597](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6597)

So i used the `ng-if` but it occupied twinkle

here [simple pan](http://codepen.io/hanquf/pen/VjKQgp?editors=1010).

when several times click  `twinkle` button, you can see the twinkle Word bunch on the button below

I would like to remove the twinkle Word bunch
:(  help me...

Comment: It seems to work okay. I don't see any bunch after clicking several times.

Comment: hmmmmmm.... if quick clik can see............

Answer (score 0):

There does appear to be a problem with `ng-if`. When clicking rapidly the words sometime appear bunched up under the button. This doesn't seem to be the case with `ng-show`. I have removed the `ng-if` from each `md-grid-tile` and placed a `ng-show` in the `md-grid-list` and moved the button out of the `md-grid-list`. The bunched up words no longer appear under the button and the `md-grid-list` only occupies space when `val` is true as can be seen by the position of the blue square.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/JKbwOv?editors=1010)

Markup

```
<div>
  <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="toggle()">twinkle</md-button>
</div>
<md-grid-list style="margin=10px;"md-cols="4" md-row-height="16:3" ng-show=val>
  <md-grid-tile>
    <p>TwinkleAppTwinkleAppTwinkleApp111</p>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>
    <p>TwinkleAppTwinkleAppTwinkleApp2</p>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>
    <p>TwinkleAppTwinkleAppTwinkleApp3</p>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>
    <p>TwinkleAppTwinkleAppTwinkleApp4</p>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>
    <p>TwinkleAppTwinkleAppTwinkleApp5</p>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile>
    <p>TwinkleAppTwinkleAppTwinkleApp6</p>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
<div style="background:blue; width:100px; height:100px; margin-top:20px;">
```

Comment: thanks answer but.. i want use `ng-if` because `ng-show` use occupy the space. #6597(https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6597)